# AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Cannot wrap non-Error object

Tags: cloudinary, strapi, uploading

When i try to upload Image using strapi on cloudinary then it says internal server error on strapi backend  and gives me this error AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Cannot wrap non-Error object  in terminal. I don't know what is the problem, Help me to resolve this issue thanx

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Create a directory path './config/plugins.js' from the root of your Strapi application

Copy and paste the code below in your plugins.js file and change the details of the providerOptions object.

```js
    // ./config/plugins.js
    
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
      module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
        // ...
        upload: {
          provider: "cloudinary",
          providerOptions: {
            cloud_name: env("process.env.CLOUDINARY_NAME"),
            api_key: env("process.env.CLOUDINARY_KEY"),
            api_secret: env("process.env.CLOUDINARY_SECRET"),
          },
        },
        // ...
      });
    } else {
      module.exports = {};
    }
```

Step 2: Create a .env file at the root of your Strapi application. Copy your api secret, api key and api environment variable from your cloudinary dashboard and save in the .env file.

```js
CLOUDINARY_URL=cloudinary://CLOUDINARY_API_KEY:CLOUDINARY_API_KEY@CLOUDINARY_NAME
CLOUDINARY_NAME=CLOUDINARY_NAME
CLOUDINARY_API_KEY=CLOUDINARY_API_KEY
CLOUDINARY_API_KEY=CLOUDINARY_API_KEY
```

This worked for me. I hope it should work for you too.